# Magento 2 form not posting

Tags: magento-2.1, forms

I have a Magento 2.1.7 theme and a form in the footer.phtml that I am trying to get to submit the form fields to a php file that is external from Magento. 
My issue is when I click the submit button in the form I get brought to the file that is indivated in the action of the form element. However none of my posted variables are being shown to the page.  I am not sure why my form posts are not working.

Below is the form in the magento footer.phtml file. NOTE the form action when viewed on front end inspection shows https://www . mydomain . com/newsletter_subscribe  where "mydomain.com" is my actual domain name

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $block->getUrl(); ?>newsletter_subscribe" class="form subscribe">
        <input type='text' class='hbox' name='email'><input type="hidden" name='region' value='<?php echo "$storeID";?>'>
        <div class="field newsletter">
            <label class="label" for="footer_newsletter"><span><?php echo __('Sign Up for Our Newsletter:') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="adr" type="text" id="footer_newsletter" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}" placeholder="Enter Your Email"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <button class="action subscribe primary" title="<?php echo __('Subscribe') ?>" type="submit">
                <span><?php echo __('Subscribe') ?></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Below is my code in the external from magento2 php file

```
<?php
   //subscribe user to emme newsletter list
   $countrycode = $_POST['region'];
   $emailaddris = $_POST['adr'];
   $spambox = $_POST['email'];

   echo "$spambox a $emailaddris and the country is  $countrycode";
```

?>

Comment: Hi, could you put print_r($_REQUEST); in your file and see what it is request header from the submitted form.

Comment: If I put print_r($_REQUEST); it just shows Array ( ) to the page

Comment: Please use action like <?php echo $block->getUrl('moduleflFrontname/controllerName/actionName');?>

Comment: Please keep firebug and check in the front end how it showing the action url.?